# What does this "solely" explain?

Tags: grammar

What does this "solely" explain?

"NPR is solely responsible for its content."

Is it, "NPR is responsible only for its content, so we don't know about other info."

Or

"Only NPR is responsible for its content, so CNN or other media companies are not involved here"??

Comment: "sole responsibility" is a set expression. It cannot be interpreted in any other way than that "NPR, and NPR alone, is responsible." Context does not allow parsing in other ways.

Comment: **sole 2** belonging to one person or group; not shared *She has sole responsibility for the project.* (http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/sole_1)

Answer (score 3):

You have found an interesting ambiguity.

*Solely* is an adverb modifying the predicate adjective *responsible*. Omitting *solely* we have

> NPR is responsible for its content.

As you imply, there are at least two interpretations for *solely*.

> NPR *alone* [and no one else] is responsible for its content.
>
> and
>
> NPR is responsible only for its *content* [but not for its style/financing/political fallout, etc.]
>
> and possibly,
>
> NPR is responsible only for *its* content [but not for the content of others]

I think most listeners would intuit the first (and I think that is what is intended), but the latter two are not logically or grammatically excluded.

Answer (score -3):

Essentially, NPR is responsible only for their content, not content from others.

Comment: That's not the way I have interpreted that statement in the past.  I believe they mean to say that they alone are responsible for what you hear on NPR. I.e., nobody else should be blamed for anything that's said.  It all comes down to how the *it's* is emphasized (or not emphasized) when spoken, and they don't emphasize it.

Comment: Makes sense that way...interested to hear opinions of others as well.

Comment: Always try to cite your sources.

Comment: *Solely* is not *only*, as your answer recognizes.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Looking at it again, you are correct.  Posting early in the morning when I can't sleep (i.e. 3:13am) apparently doesn't produce quality answers.  I'll avoid that in the future.